# Application for streaming & downloading YouTube simultaneously

Tags: windows, video, web-browser, youtube

I used to live on YouTube for some of my learning & research. I'm looking for a way other than the offline playback feature provided by YouTube in which I can search and play videos, and when I play a video it automatically gets downloaded on my hard drive in my chosen video format. Is there any application available for my need? I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: Do you want a standalone application, or something that works inside your browser? Which browser? What search features are you looking for other than what you get on the normal website?

Comment: As i searched and found there is no application which fully according to my need so for now i just want a application which can stream and download simultaneously. In Firefox you can download YouTube videos but there is no way in which streaming video which is actually downloaded somewhere in temp folder on hard drive is get saved as your chosen folder after completion, something like that. I'm on chrome and Firefox both.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't fully meet your requirement, but you can try flashgot for firefox, it gives a download media button whenever media is playing for any format which the site offers.

Disclaimer: Downloading youtube videos may be against Google's TOS, so do your own legal research.

Comment: It is against the YouTube EULA, you're correct

Comment: I know all other ways for downloading YouTube videos so please don't suggest them in answers. What I'm looking is in my question and comment.